# Is there a faster way of repeating a chunk of code x times and taking an average?

Tags: python, numpy

Starting with:

```
    a,b=np.ogrid[0:n+1:1,0:n+1:1]
    B=np.exp(1j*(np.pi/3)*np.abs(a-b))
    B[z,b] = np.exp(1j * (np.pi/3) * np.abs(z - b +x))
    B[a,z] = np.exp(1j * (np.pi/3) * np.abs(a - z +x))
    B[diag,diag]=1-1j/np.sqrt(3)
```

this produces an n*n grid that acts as a matrix.

n is just a number chosen to represent the indices, i.e. an a*b matrix where a and b both go up to n.

Where z is a constant I choose to replace a row and column with the B[z,b] and B[a,z] formulas. (Essentially the same formula but with a small number added to the np.abs(a-b))

The diagonal of the matrix is given by the bottom line:

```
B[diag,diag]=1-1j/np.sqrt(3)
```

where,

```
diag=np.arange(n+1)
```

I would like to repeat this code 50 times where the only thing that changes is x so I will end up with 50 versions of the B np.ogrid. x is a randomly generated number between -0.8 and 0.8 each time.

```
x=np.random.uniform(-0.8,0.8)
```

I want to generate 50 versions of B with random values of x each time and take a geometric average of the 50 versions of B using the definition:

```
def geo_mean(y):
   y = np.asarray(y)
   return np.prod(y ** (1.0 / y.shape[0]), axis=-1)
```

I have tried to set B as a function of some index and then use a for _ in range(): loop, this doesn't work. Aside from copy and pasting the block 50 times and denoting each one as B1, B2, B3 etc; I can't think of another way of working this out.

EDIT:

I'm now using part of a given solution in order to show clearly what I am looking for:

```
#A matrix with 50 random values between -0.8 and 0.8 to be used in the loop
X=np.random.uniform(-0.8,0.8, (50,1))
#constructing the base array before modification by random x values in position z
 a,b = np.ogrid[0:n+1:1,0:n+1:1]
 B = np.exp(1j * ( np.pi / 3) * np.abs( a - b ))
 B[diag,diag] = 1 - 1j / np.sqrt(3)
#list to store all modified arrays
 randomarrays = []
 for i in range( 0,50 ):
#copy array and modify it
    Bnew = np.copy( B )
    Bnew[z, b] = np.exp( 1j * ( np.pi / 3 ) * np.abs(z - b + X[i]))
    Bnew[a, z] = np.exp( 1j * ( np.pi / 3 ) * np.abs(a - z + X[i]))
    randomarrays.append(Bnew)

 Bstack = np.dstack(randomarrays)
#calculate the geometric mean value along the axis that was the row in 2D arrays
 B0 = geo_mean(Bstack)
```

From this example, every iteration of `i` uses the same value of `X`, I can't seem to get a way to get each new loop of i to use the next value in the matrix `X`. I am unsure of the ++ action in python, I know it does not work in python, I just don't know how to use the python equivalent. I want a loop to use a value of `X`, then the next loop to use the next value and so on and so forth so I can `dstack` all the matrices at the end and find a `geo_mean` for each element in the stacked matrices.

Comment: Imho it is not clear, what you are asking for. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) What is `n, z, diag`? Is this self explanatory?

Comment: @MrT I have added clarification to the post per those variables.

Comment: Is this a toy example or your actual problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One pedestrian way would be to use a list comprehension or generator expression:

```
>>> def f(n, z, x):
...     diag = np.arange(n+1)
...     a,b=np.ogrid[0:n+1:1,0:n+1:1]
...     B=np.exp(1j*(np.pi/3)*np.abs(a-b))
...     B[z,b] = np.exp(1j * (np.pi/3) * np.abs(z - b +x))
...     B[a,z] = np.exp(1j * (np.pi/3) * np.abs(a - z +x))
...     B[diag,diag]=1-1j/np.sqrt(3)
...     return B
... 
>>> X = np.random.uniform(-0.8, 0.8, (10,))
>>> np.prod((*map(np.power, map(f, 10*(4,), 10*(2,), X), 10 * (1/10,)),), axis=0)
```

But in your concrete example we can do much better than that;
using the identity `exp(a) x exp(b) = exp(a + b)` we can convert the geometric mean after exponentiation to an arithmetic mean before exponentition. A bit of care is required because of the multivaluedness of the complex n-th root which occurs in the geometric mean. In the code below we normalize the angles occurring to range -pi, pi so as to always hit the same branch as the n-th root.

Please also note that the `geo_mean` function you provide is definitely wrong. It fails the basic sanity check that taking the average of copies of the same thing should return the same thing. I've provided a better version. It is still not perfect, but I think there actually is no perfect solution, because of the nonuniqueness of the complex root.

Because of this I recommend taking the average before exponentiating. As long as your random spread is less than pi this allows a well-defined averaging procedure with an average that is actually close to the samples

```
import numpy as np

def f(n, z, X, do_it_pps_way=True):
    X = np.asanyarray(X)
    diag = np.arange(n+1)
    a,b=np.ogrid[0:n+1:1,0:n+1:1]
    B=np.exp(1j*(np.pi/3)*np.abs(a-b))
    X = X.reshape(-1,1,1)
    if do_it_pps_way:
        zbx = np.mean(np.abs(z-b+X), axis=0)
        azx = np.mean(np.abs(a-z+X), axis=0)
    else:
        zbx = np.mean((np.abs(z-b+X)+3) % 6 - 3, axis=0)
        azx = np.mean((np.abs(a-z+X)+3) % 6 - 3, axis=0)
    B[z,b] = np.exp(1j * (np.pi/3) * zbx)
    B[a,z] = np.exp(1j * (np.pi/3) * azx)
    B[diag,diag]=1-1j/np.sqrt(3)
    return B

def geo_mean(y):
    y = np.asarray(y)
    dim = len(y.shape)
    y = np.atleast_2d(y)
    v = np.prod(y, axis=0) ** (1.0 / y.shape[0])
    return v[0] if dim == 1 else v

def geo_mean_correct(y):
    y = np.asarray(y)
    return np.prod(y ** (1.0 / y.shape[0]), axis=0)

# demo that orig geo_mean is wrong
B = np.exp(1j * np.random.random((5, 5)))
# the mean of four times the same thing should be the same thing:
if not np.allclose(B, geo_mean([B, B, B, B])):
    print('geo_mean failed')
if np.allclose(B, geo_mean_correct([B, B, B, B])):
    print('but geo_mean_correct works')

n, z, m = 10, 3, 50

X = np.random.uniform(-0.8, 0.8, (m,))
B0 = f(n, z, X, do_it_pps_way=False)
B1 = np.prod((*map(np.power, map(f, m*(n,), m*(z,), X), m * (1/m,)),), axis=0)
B2 = geo_mean_correct([f(n, z, x) for x in X])

# This is the recommended way:
B_recommended = f(n, z, X, do_it_pps_way=True)

print()
print(np.allclose(B1, B0))
print(np.allclose(B2, B1))
```

Comment: Do I need to place a `D=` in front of the `np.prod` line you have at the bottom? When I try to `print(D)` without a `D=` in the last line, D comes back undefined. Also, when I put a `D=` in front and then try to `print(D)`, it looks vastly different to the matrix produced according to my `B` example in terms of the dimensions, not the actual values (they will obviously be different).

Comment: replacing the line in question (`np.prod` the bottom line) with: `B=np.prod((*map(np.power, map(f, 10*(n,), 10*(z,), X), 10 * (1/10,)),), axis=0)` appears to work, in regards to the `geo_mean` mean code, I'm not sure which axis to use, I haven't run into any issues using `1` so far. Sorry for the multiple replies!

Comment: ah yes, `f(4, 2, X.mean())` is exactly the kind of thing I was looking for to simplify the expression for `B`, however, from the code I'm assuming that is taking the average of 50 values of `X` and using that? I was looking for producing 50 matrices for `B` where in each instance of `B` a random value of `X` is generated and used and producing a geometric average of the 50 versions of the `B` matrices. I was looking for an automated way of producing `B1, B2, B3 ... B50` to be able to use my definition of `geo_mean`

Comment: I will also change axis to 0 in the `geo_mean` chunk, I did check, and with `f(4, 2, X.mean())` the dimensions are the same, the result is correct but for `X.mean` instead of the issue I am trying (I hope it is clear) to explain above!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165592/discussion-between-luke-and-paul-panzer).

Comment: @Luke, I've further expanded the answer. I hope it is clear and you find everything you need.

Comment: I've tried all of your versions of B (B0, B1, B2 and B_recommended) but they all use the same random value of `X` each time. I'm trying to get a different value of `X` for each version of `B`. i.e. `X`=0.0123123.. in `B1` and `X`=-0.4543223.. in `B2` so the geo_mean of all the versions of `B` is actually worth doing, if `B1`=`B2`=`B3`... there's no point in the geo_mean function? 

I was looking for a method to automate this idea, instead of generating a single column matrix with 50 random values from the `np.random.uniform` command and calling each element to each line of `B1` or `B2` etc

Comment: @Luke `X` is a vector, it contains 50 different random values. The average is taken over those. `B0`, `B1`, `B2` are the result **after** averaging using different methods. I'm using the same set of values `X` in all of them to make them comparable side-by-side. The creation of the full stack of `B`s one for each component if `X` is optimized out in most methods.

Comment: I don't need to worry about averaging `X`, just `B`, I just need 50 `B` matrices each using a different value of `X` so I can `geo_mean` the individual elements in the same positions of the matrices. I'm trying to take an average of 50 `B` matrices as one value of `X` in 1 `B` matrix gives a zig-zag oscillation when plot on a graph. I need to average 50 `B` matrices all using different `X` values to smooth out the zig zag oscillation.

Comment: @Luke Please take it from me that I fully understand what you are asking for and have indeed addressed it in the answer. If you take a minute and look at `B2` you'll find it is computed by applying (the corrected) `geo_mean` to a stack of 50 B's created from different `x`s. If you can't see it from the code, please just try it (take the argument `[f(n, z, x) for x in X]` and print it). The lines at the end of the script (the ones containing `allclose`) then show that the other methods avoiding the 50 different `B`s give the exact same result. Except for `B_recommended` which is more correct.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should rely more on numpy functionality, when approaching your problem. Not a numpy expert myself, so there is surely room for improvement:

```
from scipy.stats import gmean

n = 2
z = 1
a = np.arange(n + 1).reshape(1, n + 1)
#constructing the base array before modification by random x values in position z
B = np.exp(1j * (np.pi / 3) * np.abs(a - a.T))
B[a, a] = 1 - 1j / np.sqrt(3)
#list to store all modified arrays
random_arrays = []
for _ in range(50):
    #generate random x value
    x=np.random.uniform(-0.8, 0.8)
    #copy array and modify it
    B_new = np.copy(B)
    B_new[z, a] = np.exp(1j * (np.pi / 3) * np.abs(z - a + x))
    B_new[a, z] = np.exp(1j * (np.pi / 3) * np.abs(a - z + x))
    random_arrays.append(B_new)

#store all B arrays as a 3D array
B_stack = np.stack(random_arrays)
#calculate the geometric mean value along the axis that was the row in 2D arrays
geom_mean_for_rows = gmean(B_stack, axis = 2)
```

It uses the geometric mean function from [`scipy.stats`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.gmean.html) module to have a vectorised approach for this calculation.